# How to use a regex capture group in redshift (or alternative)

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a field in a redshift column that looks like the following:

`abcd1234df-TEXT_I-WANT`

the characters and numbers in the first 10 digits can be either letters or numbers.

If I use a capture group regex, I would use a poorly written expression like `(\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\W)(.*)` and grap the 2nd group

But I'm having trouble implementing this in redshift, so not sure how I can grab only the stuff after the first hyphen

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned before, regex might be an overkill. However, it could be useful in some cases.

Here's a basic [replace](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_REPLACE.html) pattern:

```
SELECT
    regexp_replace(
      'abcd1234df-TEXT_I-WANT'  -- use your input column here instead
    , '^[a-z0-9]{10}-(.*)$'     -- matches whole string, captures "TEXT_I-WANT" in $1
    , '$1'                      -- inserts $1 to return TEXT_I-WANT
    )
;
```

Answer (score 4):

@wp78de gives a very good advice to use [REGEX_REPLACE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_REPLACE.html). I allows you to choose the capture group. Using your regex, it would look like that, although you don't need 2 groups in here and using one is sufficient here.

```
select 
  regexp_replace(
    'abcd1234df-TEXT_I-WANT',
    '(\\w\\w\\w\\w\\w\\w\\w\\w\\w\\w\\W)(.*)', 
    '$2' -- replacement selecting 2nd capture group
  );
```

Another oprion, although less flexible is using [REGEX_SUBSTR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html) with `e` parameter set (*Extract a substring using a subexpression*). It allows you to select a substring, but **only of a first capture group** in your regex. You also have to set the *position* and *occurence* parameters to default `1`:

Using REGEX you suggested, but only with 1 group:

```
select 
  regexp_substr(
    'abcd1234df-TEXT_I-WANT',
    '\\w\\w\\w\\w\\w\\w\\w\\w\\w\\w\\W(.*)', 
    1, -- position
    1, -- occurrence
    'e' -- parameters
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions might be overkill.  Basic string operations are good enough:

```
select substring(col from position('-' in col) + 1)
```

Comment: thank you! i was only doing regex because of the random other hyphens

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `charindex` and `substring`.

```
substring(col,charindex('-',col)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can get the desired string by using the common table expression with `regexp_substr` as below :*

```
with cte as
(
 select 'abcd1234df-TEXT_I-WANT' as str   
)    
select regexp_substr(str,'-.*') 
       as derived_str
  from cte;

derived_str
-------------
-TEXT_I-WANT
```