# String Regex Expressions in Redshift SQL

Tags: sql, regex, string, amazon-redshift

I am pretty new to using string operations in SQL(Redshift). I want to extract a part of a string from the strings of the following format:

I can have strings of the format:

```
http://bunnytalks.com/goingOn?name=Bunny&phone=2340
http://bunnytalks.com/goingOn?name=Bunny
http://bunnytalks.com/goingOn?name=Talks/whatson%goingOn%name%Bunny
http://bunnytalks.com/goingOn?name=Talks/whatson%goingOn%name%Bunny&phone=2340
```

The final output I need from any of the above strings when applying regex:

```
Bunny
```

From the above string examples, I can tell that I need a string between the last occurrence of a `name` followed by either `=` or `%` and the end of the string or before `&`

I need a regex/ any string operations in SQL that can achieve the above operations as shown in examples. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.*name[%=]([^&\n]+)
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/9FyBSL/1)

---

`.*name` - match the last `name`

`[%=]` - followed by `%` or `=`

`([^&\n]+)` - match all non-`&`, non-`\n` characters as group 1

Comment: Even `\w` would be enough: https://regex101.com/r/OB0M9r/1

Comment: Hi, thank you. I find its working as expected in the demos shared. But when I do a Redshift query - `select regexp_substr('http://bunnytalks.com/goingOn?name=Talks/whatson%goingOn%name%Bunny','.*name[%=]([^&\n]+)')` it is not giving the expected result. I got `http://bunnytalks.com/goingOn?name=Talks/whatson%goingOn%name%Bunny`

Comment: @BunnyTalks I don't have experience with Redshift, but this answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/54826326/10035985 (basically, you want to get the value of first capturing group)

Comment: Thank you @AndrejKesely, will check it. Just for additional context. I used this site - https://www.regextester.com/99656 to test the demo link you shared for SQL.