# Extract query parameter value from url with Redshift

Tags: sql, url, amazon-redshift, extract, query-string

Is it possible to extract the value of a query parameter from a url in redshift?

For example, lets say my url is

```
https://awesomesite.com/salespage?gclid=a2x-31x_91
```

Is there some utility or regex that would allow me to extract the value of the `gclid` query parameter, `a2x-31x_91`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific query-parameter key in mind, [its pretty easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679113/getting-all-url-parameters-using-regex) to draft a regex to capture it. For `gclid` for example, the regex would be `[\?&;]gclid=([^&|;]+)`, where the capture group contains the value.

Given that, we can use redshift's `REGEXP_REPLACE` method to extract the value from the url:

```sql
select REGEXP_REPLACE(url, '.*[\?&;]gclid=([^&|;]+).*', '$1')
```

*Note: we use `REGEXP_REPLACE` instead of `REGEXP_SUBSTR` [in order to return the capture group's value, instead of the whole match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710794/how-to-use-a-regex-capture-group-in-redshift-or-alternative)*

Finally, we can generalize this solution to work for any given query-parameter key with the following function

```sql
/**
 * extracts the value of a query parameter from a url, using regex
 */
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_queryparam_from_url(url varchar, key varchar)
    RETURNS varchar
    IMMUTABLE
    AS $$
        select
            CASE WHEN (REGEXP_REPLACE($1, '.*[\?&;]' || $2 || '=([^&|;]+).*', '$1') = $1)
                THEN null -- if nothing was replaced, no match
                ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE($1, '.*[\?&;]' || $2 || '=([^&|;]+).*', '$1') -- otherwise, this will be the capture group's value
            END
    $$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

usage

```
select get_queryparam_from_url(route, 'gclid')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    'https://awesomesite.com/salespage?gclid=a2x-31x_91' AS txt,
    regexp_substr(txt,'=(.+)$', 1, 1, 'e') AS clean_txt
```